# push_back() and push_front() in Java

Tags: java, collections, vector, push-back

Is there any collection class in java, that implements `push_back()` and `push_front()` methods?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The class [`java.util.LinkedList`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) has addFirst/Last(), getFirst/last() and removeFirst/Last().

Comment: push_back() = addLast(), push_front() = addFirst().

Answer (score 7):

Any collection that implements [`Deque`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) should have it (`ArrayDeque`, `LinkedList`)

Comment: @Jerome, in the absence of a request for a specific version, I think it's okay to assume that an answer can assume any version. You could just as easily complain that your answer requires 1.2 :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `List` appears to with both `add` functions.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: Hmm, List is an interface and both variants of add are specifically marked as optional, throwing UnsupportedOperationException if the add method is not supported by the concrete class. It happens that all known implementing classes support both variants but not necessarily all user-defined ones. You might want to make that clear.